# Finding velocity from a deceleration equation

Tags: javascript, animation, exponential

Assuming we have this deceleration equation:

```
function getVelocity(elapsedTime, startOffset, initialVelocity, decelerationRate) {

  var offset = startOffset +
    (initialVelocity / (1 - decelerationRate)) *
    (1 - Math.exp(-(1 - decelerationRate) * elapsedTime));

  return // Answer goes here.
}
```

How do I find the `velocity` given `elapsedTime`?

The `startOffset` can be `0`.

The `decelerationRate` can be `0.998`.

The `initialVelocity` can be `0.5`.

Comment: This is a question about maths rather than code, is it not?

Comment: @millerbr My use case is Javascript. Perhaps you're right though.

Comment: Assuming `startValue` and `initialVelocity` are different, what is `startValue`?

Comment: Do you just want to wrap that in a function, like `function getCurrentVelocity(currentTime, startTime, initialVelocity, decelerationRate, startValue) {
  if(currentTime >= startTime) {
    return startValue +
  (initialVelocity / (1 - decelerationRate)) *
  (1 - Math.exp(-(1 - decelerationRate) * (currentTime - startTime)));
  } else {
    throw 'current time must be later that start time';
  }
}`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what is your definition of `velocity`, but assuming `offset` is a position, I think it's the derivative of your function by the time.

So you should be able to find the velocity at a time `elapsedTime` using this formula:

```
return initialVelocity * Math.exp(-(1 - decelerationRate) * time)
```

My math is a bit rusty, so don't hesitate to double check or correct me.

---

First answer:

```
return (initialVelocity / (1 - decelerationRate)) *
           (1 - decelerationRate) *
           Math.exp(-(1 - decelerationRate) * time)
```

Comment: But don't the first two `(1 - decelerationRate)` cancel each other out?

Comment: @aleclarson They do. Also it's worth to extract them in a variable when computing `offset`